# Heavy Performance Issue on atomic Function running on NVIDIA K5000

Tags: performance, cuda, nvidia, atomic

I have a heavy performance issue when running this code on NVIDIA K5000:

`while ( atomicMax(&iThreadSemaphore, 0) )
    ;`

On a GTX 650 ti or K2000 the device function is executed in ~2900 msec including the above code. On a K5000 the exactly same device function is executed in ~5000 msec. When I remove the `while` loop then the K5000 executes the device function in ~900 msec which is 1/3 of the K2000 and OK!

Has anybody an idea why the `atomicMax()` function slows the K5000 that much down?

I could definitely isolate the problem code - it is the `while` loop.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example someone else could compile and run?

Comment: Please provide more context, are other threads competing over the same semaphore? if so you'll do a lot of busy waiting

Comment: @Talonmies: I cannot provide complete example.

Comment: @Leeor: The point is GTX 650 TI and K2000 do not have any problem with the statement. Only K5000 is wasting time.

Comment: @AlBundy: can you at least explain how many threads per block and blocks you are running on each device? And is the code such that every thread is trying to atomically acquire the semaphore simultaneously? The answer is probably that the K5000 has 8SM, whereas the others have only 4. That means, theoretically, twice as many threads simultaneously contenting for the same resource via an atomic transaction. Should you be surprised that it is slower?

Comment: @Talonmies: This example is running 147 blocks 146 threads each. Yes, every thread is trying to atomically acquire the semaphore simultaneously. I am thinking about what you wrote. May be it is a design problem in my code.

Comment: @AlBundy, you probably got your answer, but in the future try to provide more info in your question. You didn't even say that it was the same semaphore shared by all threads.

Comment: @Leeor: I see and will try to provide more accurate information; for me it was clear since I called the variable `iThreadSemaphore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your problem sounds like a straightforward example of scalability limitations in your code.

The K5000 has 8 multiprocessors, whereas the others have only 4 multiprocessors. Given that you say you are running 147 blocks (which is more than enough to complete fill all of the GPUs during execution), you will have a situation where the K5000 will have about twice as many threads in flight at one time as the K2000 or GF650Ti. From the extremely limited description of your code, that would mean  that you have twice as many threads contending for the same semaphore atomically. The more contention you have, the slower the code will be. I would expect twice as much contention for the same atomic resource to be at least twice as slow.

In summary, it would appear that there is nothing wrong with your K5000, except that it is large enough to expose serious scalability problems with your code.